# Django filtering with nested queries

Tags: python, django, django-models, filter, django-queryset

I have a Django model that looks roughly like this

```
class Equipment(models.Model):
    id = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)

class Tag(models.Model):  
    id = models.UUIDField(default=uuid.uuid4, unique=True, primary_key=True)
    tag_type = models.ForeignKey(TagType)
    equipment = models.ForeignKey(Equipment)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)

    class Meta:
        db_table = "tag"
        ordering = ["tag_type__name", "name"]
        unique_together = (("tag_type", "equipment"),)

class TagType(models.Model):  
    id = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(primary_key=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100, unique=True)

    class Meta:
        db_table = "tag_type"
        ordering = ["name"]
```

TagTypes have names such as "Equipment" and "Load"

"Equipment" tags can be "HVAC" or "Lighting"

"Load" tags can be "Variable" or "Weather"

I want to be able to filter to equipment that have a certain tag_type with a tag name.

If I want equipment that have an `HVAC` tag with tag_type `Equipment` the following works:
`Equipment.objects.filter(tag__tag_type__name="Equipment", tag__name="HVAC")`

However, I believe that in this case the tag_type name and the tag aren't necessarily from the same tag. AKA `tag__tag_type__name="Equipment"` and `tag__name="HVAC"` might not be referring with the right values.

Since there can be many different types of tags with diverse names, I want to make sure I'm filtering to the right one. Is there a way I can manage this?

Comment: Why do you think that the tag_type and the tag_typ_name are not from the same type?

Comment: Well say there is an equipment with two tags associated with it. One tag has tag_type.name=="Equipment" & tag.name=="Fan". The other tag has tag_type.name=="Icon" & tag.name=="HVAC". I believe the filter call I show in my post would have this in the query set when I only want equipment with a tag like tag_type.name=="Equipment" & tag.name=="HVAC".

Comment: So I guess what you'll need is to filter on the Tag table:
tags = Tags.objects.filter(type_name = 'Equipement', name = 'HVAC) and take the results [x.equipement for x in tags]

Comment: Why is Equipment a Fk on Tag and not the other way around?

Comment: There can be many tags for any equipment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some further testing, by chaining `tag__tag_type__name="Equipment"` and  `tag__name="HVAC"` together ensures that it is indeed looking at the same tag. My worries were unfounded